# $() prior to willInsertElement

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I have a `<select`> box that defines a "thing" and sets `model.thing` and the view is observing a change in that model, then doing some jQuery noise in response. Example:

```
FooNewView = Ember.View.extend

  selectedThing: (->
    @setNameIfUnset()
  ).observes('controller.model.thing')

  setNameIfUnset: () ->
    console.log 'setNameIfUnset'
    unless @$('#name-field').val().length
      # set the name to the name of Thing if not set yet

  didInsertElement: () ->
    @_super()
    Ember.Logger.info("FooNewView::didInsertElement")
```

Trouble is, the observer seems to fire *once* before didInsertElement is called, therefore `this.$()` is undefined at this point.

My question is: what is the best way to handle this? Should I just set a flag in `didInsertElement` and check that in `setNameIfUnset`? Maybe just a plain old jQuery `change` listener added to `didInsertElement`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is check if `this.$()` is defined before executing the code in `observer` rather setting unnecessary flags and jquery listeners. so code will be

```
setNameIfUnset: function(){
   if(this.$()) {
       console.log('setNameIfUnset');
       unless @$('#name-field').val().length
      # set the name to the name of Thing if not set yet
   }
}
```